# Is there a fast method to open the Format> Font dialog?

Tags: fonts

I would like to rephrase my  older quastion about shortcuts. Excuse me for any possibe dublicates!

My problem is that I spend a lot of time to go to menu Format> Font>  choose a font and  a font size. I have a lot of fonts ( my Mathematica programming Knowledge is also very narrow...) and  I have no idea how this could be done. So my questions are:

Is there a way to "insert" the Fonts dialog right on the Frontend in the same way it appears in Microsoft Word for example or

Is it possible to use FrontEndExecute command to do this task programmatically?( Maybe the second method is better because  I hope that one could also choose a particular font(lets say Courier) and a size( 8) with just on [Shift][Enter] )

Comment: If you need additional help, let us know and someone will improve the answers in the other thread.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, you should take a look at LaTeX, which is *far* better than Mathematica for writing books in mathematics and is super useful, although it's also somewhat more difficult.

Comment: From the docs `FrontEndTokenExecute["FontPanel"]`

Comment: @bobthechemist Thank you! This is realy much easier! Could you please help me find a way for fast selecting a particular font and size?